# how do i install ant-junit in redhat

Tags: redhat

I am trying to install ant-junit in Redhat Linux 7. [image]I have given the command as yum install -y ant ant-junit. Ant has installed but I am getting an error as no package available for ant-junit.

Answer (score 0):

I have typed the below command and it Worked!!

cd /tmp
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/ant-junit-1.9.4-2.el7.noarch.rpm

yum install ant-junit-1.9.4-2.el7.noarch.rpm

Answer (score 0):

The official Red Hat solution to this problem is to install the `rh-java-common` Software Collection packages.
You will need to enable the Software Collections repository. If you're using `subscription-manager`, it can be done as follows. If your organization manages what repositories are enabled on your machine, you will need to contact your IT department or manager to determine how to enable additional Red Hat repositories.

```
% subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-workstation-scls-7-rpms
% yum install rh-java-common-ant-junit
```

After the packages are installed (you'll get a newer version of Ant in the Software Collection as well as `ant-junit`), you'll need to enable the Software Collection either for the invocation of `ant` or for a new shell:

```
$ scl enable rh-java-common ant
```

OR

```
$ scl enable rh-java-common /bin/bash
$ ant
```